# Custom container view controller children presenting subview controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

My container view controller contains several sub view controllers each of which may present additional view controllers themselves using

```
[self presentViewController:mySubViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But these presented view controllers are not part of the parent container's view heirarchy - which is important for functionality and presentation. How do I add them to it? Must it be explicate by the child view controller or is it possible to do by the parent container - which has no knowledge of what will be presented by its children?

Answer (score 0):

They will be added to the view hierarchy, as said [in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController%3aanimated%3acompletion%3a):

> **Discussion**
>   (...)
>   This method sets the presentedViewController property to the specified
>   view controller, resizes that view controller’s view and **then adds the
>   view to the view hierarchy**. The view is animated onscreen according to
>   the transition style specified in the modalTransitionStyle property of
>   the presented view controller.